# SQLite and elisp?

Tags: sqlite, elisp

Is there SQLite wrapper for elisp?

If not, is it a good idea to call python code that takes control of SQLite through start-process or something? Is there better way to use SQLite from elisp?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Trey Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571574/sqlite-and-elisp/3572213#3572213)'s starting link, there seems to be a tutorial on how to **build** [a programmatic interface for elisp to an inferior-process sqlite](http://mysite.verizon.net/mbcladwell/connect-to-emacs.html), e.g. `sqlite-query<f>`. It is based on screen-scraping a [comint buffer](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ComintMode) just for this purpose (e.g. not reusing sql.el). The following is an incomplete example copied from that reference.

```
;; this is emacs lisp code
(defun sqlite-query ( sql-command )
 (set-buffer sqlite-output-buffer)          ;1
 (erase-buffer)                                 ;2
  (comint-redirect-send-command-to-process
    sql-command
    sqlite-output-buffer
    (get-buffer-process sqlite-process-buffer) nil)  ;3
  (accept-process-output
    (get-buffer-process sqlite-process-buffer)
     1)  ;need to wait to obtain results

  (let*  ((begin (goto-char (point-min)))       ;4
      (end (goto-char (point-max)))
      (num-lines (count-lines begin end))
      (counter 0)
      (results-rows ()))
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while ( < counter num-lines)
      (setq results-rows (cons (chomp (thing-at-point 'line)) results-rows))
      (forward-line)
      (setq counter (+ 1 counter)))
    (car `(,results-rows))))
```

Unfortunately there doesn't look like there is anything off-the-shelf there, but perhaps [it is a good approach](http://mysite.verizon.net/mbcladwell/) and probably better than trying to use yet another intermediate language.

(Aside, I find that example of connecting sqlite with emacs' Widget GUI interface to be intriguing.)

Comment: I wrote a [small SQLite wrapper for Emacs Lisp](http://www.jasonfruit.com/page/emacs_sqlite_and_widgets) in response to the code here.

Answer (score 6):

[Emacs wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org) is your friend, there lies a couple of links to a couple of tools for sqlite.

[Emacs WIki SQLite](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SQLite), the first link is probably the one you're looking for: handling the interaction with the database: [sql-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SqlMode).